# Possible to incorporate color meta tag into semi-transparent background?

Tags: html, css, colors, tumblr, meta-tags

I have a meta tag for a color which I'll be using in several places in my code.

```
#wrapper #content .post {
font-family: {font:Body};
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
{block:IfRoundedCorners}border-radius: 9px{/block:IfRoundedCorners};
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
left: 100px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.1)10px 10px;
margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

As you can see, my background is white and set to an opacity of 0.9. I was wondering if the background could instead inherit the color of my meta tag `{color:Posts}` while maintaining the opacity of 0.9.

Previously, the `background-color:` line was replaced with

```
background-color: {color:Posts};
opacity:0.9;
```

and while this achieved my desired effect, it also made everything else within `.post` transparent, which is problematic, since I only want the background to be transparent.

Of course I want it to refer to the meta tag so that if ever I decide to change the colour scheme of my page, I only change a few values at the top of my code and not every place where it's used.

I should note, the meta tag uses a HEX value, so `#FFFFFF` instead of `255,255,255`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Variable Transformations**

Tumblr supplies a few keywords, that will modify a variable and change its output. In the OP example, they want to take a `HEX` color and have the output as `RGB`. To do this, prepend the variable with the letters `RGB`.

As it stands, this doesn't work completely (as it only turns the `HEX` into RGB values). We need to fill in the gaps and include an alpha channel value:

**Before**

```
background-color: rgba( {RGBcolor:Posts}, 0.9 );
```

**After**

```
background-color: rgba( 255,255,255,0.9 );
```

That's it. You can even go one step further and setup another theme operator to handle the alpha value, giving total control to the customisation options.

**Before**

```
<meta name="text:Posts Background Alpha" content="0.9">

background-color: rgba( {RGBcolor:Posts}, {text:Posts Background Alpha} );
```

**After**

```
background-color: rgba( 255,255,255,0.9 );
```